# What does Mage::getUrl('a/b/c') return in magento and how to change it?

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to use:

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('neema/index/save') ?> method="post">
```

to redirect to a page which is located at:

```
localhost/magento/index.php/neema/index/save
```

But what this does is redirecting to:

```
localhost/magento/neema/index/save
```

(no index.php)?! I have the same missing index.php problem using `_redirect('a/b/c')`.

I am not sure if the question I asked is relevant to the problem I am having, basically I am a noob.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jenny O'Reilly question looks better now and correct too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to go into the admin section an set:

```
System -> Configuration -> Web -> Search Engines Optimizations, select No.
```

This should make Magento turn on index.php when it is generating the urls.

Comment: i apologize to ask question this way but can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32249029/save-and-delete-buttons-are-missing-from-magento-adminpanel-form

Answer (score 2):

`Mage::Url()` will return the same values that you have mentioned in the `Base Url` field of the `Unsecure` section in admin. So it is working fine. First, we dont require `index.php` in the url.

So to remove the index.php from the URL, in Admin `System -> Configuration -> Web -> Search Engines Optimizations, select Yes.`

Then it will work fine.

Comment: i agree with you it will be nicer if there is no index.php in URL. But when it was yes i couldn't redirect properly. is there any way it will work without index.php.

Comment: So somewhere it is hardcoded the Url with index.php in the form action or some other place. So find it out and remove the index.php